# exception:"type was not mapped" in entityframework codefirst with layers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6, code-first

i'm trying to apply LAYERS Concept on demo project developed using mvc and entity framework both
Data Annotations : for validations in Data Access Layer and
Fluent API : for mapping and tables relations

**Problem** : DbContext didn't Create DB and there is a Runtime Exception :

### The type 'Domain.DataLayer.Member' was not mapped. Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive, nested or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.

**Code** : my solutions consists of :
1- class library (Domain.Classes project): where i wrote all of my classes

```
public class Member
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
   
}
```

2- DAL (Domain.DataLayer project): also another class library and i referenced domain.classes

```
namespace Domain.DataLayer.Repositories
{
   [MetadataType(typeof(MemberMetadata))]
   public partial class Member : Classes.Member , IValidatableObject
   {
     public Member()
     {
        Tasks = new HashSet<Task>();
        History = new HashSet<Commint>();
     }
     public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; } 
     public HashSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
     public HashSet<Commint> History { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
     {
        var result = new List<ValidationResult>();
        if (!string.Equals(Password,ConfirmPassword))
        {
            result.Add(new ValidationResult("mismatch pwsd", new[] {"ConfirmPassword" }));
        }
        return result;
     }
  } 
}
```

and i used  repository pattern :

```
public class MemberRepository : IRepository<Member>
{
    public Task<IQueryable<Member>> GetAllEntities()
    {
        return Task<IQueryable<Member>>.Factory.StartNew(() => new Context().Members.AsQueryable());
    }
}
```

3-BLL : for sake of simplicity : there is no Business Logic Layer

4- PL (Domain.Application MVC Project) : Member Controller :

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var members = await _repository.GetAllEntities();
        return View(members);
    }
```

Note : i depended on DbContext to create DB with name like : Domain.DataLayer.Context but it didn't craete DB so i created the DB and passed the connectionString through Context constructor like this :

```
namespace Domain.DataLayer
{
  public class Context : DbContext
  {
    public Context(): base("InterviewDemo") // i tried also base("name=InterviewDemo")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Commint> TaskHistory { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new MemberConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TaskConfig());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CommintConfig());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
  }
}
```